# How the coproduct defines an action on $X\otimes Y$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, hopf-algebras, coalgebras

Given a bialgebra $A$ and two $A$-modules $X$ and $Y$. We can build the tensor product of the underlying vector spaces $X\otimes Y$.

What does it mean if one says 'The $A$-module structure on $X\otimes Y$ is given via the coproduct of $A$'?

Can I also define $a.(x\otimes y):=ax\otimes ay$ or, for instance, $a.(x\otimes y):=ax\otimes y$?

Comment: No, you cannot define it to be $ax \otimes ay$. This doesn't depend linearly on $a \in A$.

Comment: Yes, you can define it to be $ax\times y$. But this isn't the $A$-module structure on $X \otimes Y$ you would want. It doesn't take the $A$-module structure on $Y$ into account; over a field, it's just a direct sum of several copies of $X$.

Answer (score 3):

The co-product is an algebra homomorphism $\Delta:A\to A\otimes A$ (so $\Delta$ is linear and $\Delta(ab)=\Delta(a)\Delta(b)$). If we write $\Delta(a)=\sum a_{(1)}\otimes a_{(2)}$, then
$$a.(x\otimes y)=\Delta(a)(x\otimes y)=\sum (a_{(1)}.x)\otimes (a_{(2)}.y).$$

For example, if $G$ is a group, then $\Delta(g)=g\otimes g$ defines a co-product on the group algebra $\mathbb{C}G$. In this case, $g.(x\otimes y)=(g.x)\otimes(g.y)$.

For a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, the co-product is given by $\Delta(a)=a\otimes 1+1\otimes a$ for $a\in \mathfrak{g}$. Therefore, $a.(x\otimes y)=(a.x)\otimes y+x\otimes(a.y)$.

Another example of a bialgebra is the ring of symmetric functions. The co-product is given by $\Delta(p_n)=p_n\otimes 1+1\otimes p_n$ for power sum symmetric functions. If you take the basis given by elementary symmetric functions, the co-product is
$$\Delta(e_n)=\sum_{k=0}^n e_{n-k}\otimes e_k.$$

Comment: Thank you very much, also for the examples! Is this the same structure as (with $\rho_X,\rho_Y$ the corresponding algebra homomorphisms and $\tau$ the flip $x\otimes y\mapsto y\otimes x$) $(\rho_X\otimes\rho_Y)\circ (id\otimes\tau\otimes id)(\Delta(a)\otimes x\otimes y)$?

Comment: Or would there be a problem because $\tau$ need not to be an algebra homomorphism?

Comment: I'm not quite sure which structure you are referring to.

Comment: What you don't understand? After applying the first (right) of the two functions I get an element like $g_1\otimes x\otimes g_2\otimes y$.

Comment: Would your answer above change, if I want the algebra $A$ to be a super-algebra? I.e. would there be a $(-1)^{...}$ be involved in the action?

Comment: @R.A.: the superalgebra case should constitute a separate question.